# How do I set size.pr in OpenLDAP?

Tags: openldap

I think one of my LDAP clients is hitting a pagination limit in OpenLDAP. The specific error the client sees is the following Java thing:

```
REASON: Caught exception running LDAP sync. 
[LDAP: error code 2 - paged results cookie is invalid]; 
nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: 
[LDAP: error code 2 - paged results cookie is invalid]; 
remaining name 'dc=example,dc=com'
```

Googling for that error brought up a discussion of LDAP pagination and relevant limits. This document on [OpenLDAP limits](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/limits.html) mentions `olcSizeLimit` and `size.pr`.

I was able to change my olcSizeLimit from 500 to -1 using this ldif:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSizeLimit
olcSizeLimit: -1
```

Unfortunately my client is still seeing its pagination issue.

`size.pr` is a slapd.conf setting, while my OpenLDAP uses slapd.d instead. After grepping around in the LDAP schema, I've found `olcDbClientPr` which is described as `'PagedResults handling'`. Also, here's how it's described in the [OpenLDAP source code](https://github.com/gcp/openldap/blob/master/servers/slapd/back-meta/config.c):

```
{ "client-pr", "accept-unsolicited|disable|<size>", 2, 2, 0,
    ARG_MAGIC|LDAP_BACK_CFG_CLIENT_PR,
    meta_back_cf_gen, "( OLcfgDbAt:3.111 "
        "NAME 'olcDbClientPr' "
        "DESC 'PagedResults handling' "
        "SYNTAX OMsDirectoryString "
        "SINGLE-VALUE )",
    NULL, NULL },
```

On the assumption that olcDbClientPr is the same thing as size.pr, how do I set it?

I've tried this:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcDbClientPr
olcDbClientPr: -1
```

It throws this error:

```
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: attribute 'olcDbClientPr' not allowed
```

In case it's relevant, here are the contents of my `cn=config` directory:

```
# ls /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/
cn=module{0}.ldif  olcDatabase={0}config.ldif     olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif
cn=schema          olcDatabase={-1}frontend.ldif  olcDatabase={1}monitor.ldif
cn=schema.ldif     olcDatabase={1}hdb
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`size.pr` is a, per database (and dn/group scopable), `olcLimits` option. You might also be interested in the global `olcSizeLimit` option.

From `slapd-config(5)`:

> **olcSizeLimit: size[.{soft|hard|unchecked}]= [...]**
>      Specify the maximum number of entries to return from a search operation. The default size limit is 500.  Use unlimited to  specify  no  limits. The  second  format allows a fine grain setting of the size limits.  Extra args can be added in the same value or as additional values.  See olcLimits for an explanation of the different flags.

---

`olcDbClientPr` is **not** the same as `size.pr`.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm still seeing the paged results cookie error in the client app, but I've now been able to set `olcLimits` to `* size.pr=unlimited size.prtotal=disabled` for `dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config` which I think is the right place